# How can I track what the user does with MFMailComposeViewController using Google Analytics?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

How can I track what the user does with MFMailViewController using Google Analytics?  I want to see how people are using it; i.e. press cancel, send an email, delete message etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a following method in your delegate:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
 id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
 switch (result) {
     case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"                                                               action:@"event_action"  // Event action (required)
            label:@"Cancelled"          // Event label
            value:nil] build]];    // Event value
          break;
     case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"                                                               action:@"event_action"  // Event action (required)
            label:@"Saved"          // Event label
            value:nil] build]];    // Event value
          break;
     case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"                                                               action:@"event_action"  // Event action (required)
            label:@"Sent"          // Event label
            value:nil] build]];    // Event value
          break;
     case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"                                                               action:@"event_action"  // Event action (required)
            label:@"Failed"          // Event label
            value:nil] build]];    // Event value
          break;
     default:
          break;
 }
}
```